# Parent Hover State when hovering over Sub Menu

Tags: css, menu

How can I include the triangle hover state to the parent link, when hovering over the sub menu links? http://website-test-lab.com/sites/tcf/locals/

Currently, the css triangle appears on hover and when on current page. If you visit the link above and hover over the ABOUT link, then hover over the sub menu you will see that the triangle disappears. I'd like it to stay.

Here's my CSS:

```
    .nav ul li a:hover:after,
.nav .current-menu-item:after,
.nav .current_page_parent:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 28px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 31px 10px 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent $pink transparent;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to change the element that triggers the `:hover` state actually you have that on the `<a>` tag change it to the `<li>`.

You have this selector:

```
.nav ul li a:hover:after
```

Change it to:

```
.nav ul li:hover > a:after
```

Comment: @HuwRowlands works fine making the change direct on your page with developer tools ... If you can replicate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net then I can show you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/huwrowlands/2sQbn/2/ <- I have got it working on JSFiddle Thanks.